# IoTivity Zigbee communication

Tags: linux, zigbee, iotivity

I am using IoTivity 1.2.0  downloaded from  https://www.iotivity.org/downloads

After connecting Telegesis Dongle to the USB port, when I use `dmesg` command in terminal I am getting following output:

```
[ 1468.177799] iotivityandzigb[3807]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000406a1a sp 00007fff58916940 error 4 in iotivityandzigbeeserver[400000+a000]
[ 1477.694759] iotivityandzigb[3817]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000406a1a sp 00007ffe520b7e90 error 4 in iotivityandzigbeeserver[400000+a000]
[ 1574.990272] iotivityandzigb[3879]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000406a1a sp 00007fff36eef7f0 error 4 in iotivityandzigbeeserver[400000+a000]
[ 1600.509959] iotivityandzigb[3892]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000406a1a sp 00007ffc0a01d770 error 4 in iotivityandzigbeeserver[400000+a000]
[ 1916.457932] iotivityandzigb[3936]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000406a1a sp 00007ffe3fc5e030 error 4 in iotivityandzigbeeserver[400000+a000]
[ 1985.551459] iotivityandzigb[4001]: segfault at 0 ip 00000000004069ff sp 00007ffc431ca040 error 4 in iotivityandzigbeeserver[400000+a000]
[ 2202.975833] iotivityandzigb[4105]: segfault at 0 ip 00000000004069ff sp 00007fff9d810760 error 4 in iotivityandzigbeeserver[400000+a000]
```

I see there is a lot of segmentation faults. How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 1):

If this is still happening with more recent code (aka 1.2.1, or 1.2-rel git branch, or master git branch), filing an issue in the iotivity tracker at jira.iotivity.org might get more attention from people familiar with this area of the code. Sorry this isn't really an "answer" but hopefully it will at least provide a path to some resolution.